Fill numpy array to the right based on previous column
I have the following states and transition matrix
import numpy as np

n_states = 3
states = np.arange(n_states)

T = np.array([
    [0.5, 0.5, 0],
    [0.5, 0,  0.5],
    [0,  0,  1]
])

I would like to simulate n_sims paths where each path consist of n_steps. Each path starts at 0. Therefore, I write
n_sims = 100
n_steps = 10
paths = np.zeros((n_sims, n_steps),  dtype=int)

With the help of np.random.Generator.choice I would like to "fill to the right" the paths using the transition matrix.
My attempt look as follows
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=123)

for s in range(1, n_steps+1):
    paths[:,s] = rng.choice(
        a=n_states,
        size=n_sim,
        p=T[paths[:,s-1]]
    )

This result in the following error:

ValueError: p must be 1-dimensional

How can I overcome this? If possible, I would like to prevent for-loops and vectorize the code.

Can you explain the logic? Also provide a small example (n_sims = 7 for example) with an example of the expected output!

Also you pass a scalar as a to rng.choices, so p should be an 1d array of size n_states. But again, without describing the expected logic, it's difficult to comment on your failed attempt.

IIUC, your process being inherently iterative, you won't benefit much from numpy's vectorization.
You might want to consider using pure python:
def simulation(T, n_states=3, n_sims=100, n_steps=10, seed=123):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
    start = np.zeros(n_steps, dtype=np.int64)
    out = [start]
    for i in range(n_sims-1):
        a = np.array([rng.choice(n_states, p=T[x]) for x in start])
        out.append(a)
        start = a
    return np.array(out)
        
simulation(T, n_states=3, n_sims=100, n_steps=10)

Example output:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2],
       [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       ...
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])

